# Inconsistency in TypeConverter behavior?

Tags: c#, typeconverter

I am working on an `IValueConverter` implementation which would convert `bool?` values. For the sake of versatility I've decided to use `TypeConverter` to convert input value to `bool?`. Since its main purpose is to be used as a converter for XAML bindings I'd like to avoid having exceptions thrown as it results in significant decrease of UI performance. To do that I tried using `TypeConverter.IsValid` method, but came across peculiar behavior, an example of which is shown in the following code:

```
//returned converter is a NullableConverter
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(bool?));

//this method returns false
converter.IsValid(string.Empty);

//yet this method returns null without throwing an exception
converter.ConvertFrom(string.Empty);
```

Perhaps I'm wrong, but I'd expect the `IsValid` method to return `false` whenever a value cannot be converted and `true` otherwise, but clearly that's not the case with an empty string and `NullableConverter` (same behavior can be observed for other nullable types).

Is this a bug or rather a design choice? And if the latter, are there any other similar cases?

**EDIT**

After inspecting the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/NullableConverter.cs,0107a64f3a234d90) for `NullableConverter` I think I've found the reason for this behavior. Here's the `IsValid` implementation:

```
public override bool IsValid(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value) {
    if (simpleTypeConverter != null) {
        object unwrappedValue = value;
        if (unwrappedValue == null) {
            return true; // null is valid for nullable.
        }
        else {
            return simpleTypeConverter.IsValid(context, unwrappedValue);
        }
    }

    return base.IsValid(context, value);
}
```

In my case the `simpleTypeConverter` is of type `BooleanConverter` and, understandably, it returns `false` for `string.Empty`. On the other hand, here's the `ConvertFrom` implementation:

```
public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
    if (value == null || value.GetType() == this.simpleType) {
        return value;
    }
    else if (value is String && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as String)) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (this.simpleTypeConverter != null) {
        object convertedValue = this.simpleTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        return convertedValue;
    }
    else {
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Obviously, `string.Empty` falls into the second `if` statement, hence the `null` result without an exception.

Knowing the reason for this behavior the question still remains - is it an oversight, or is it intended to work this way? I've submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1361520) and will post any conclusions to come out of it.

Comment: When I try your example `IsValid` throws a `FormatException` with message `String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.` However, the documentations says that "Starting in .NET Framework 4, the IsValid method catches exceptions from the CanConvertFrom and ConvertFrom methods. If the input value type causes CanConvertFrom to return false, or if the input value causes ConvertFrom to raise an exception, the IsValid method returns false."

Comment: Also funny that `myNullableConverter.ConvertToString(null)` returns an empty string. I guess `null` is not valid for a `Nullable<T>`?

Comment: @MariusBancila I've just tested the code targeting framework versions ranging from 2.0 up to 4.5.1, and not in any case neither `ConvertFrom` nor `IsValid` threw an exception. Interestingly though, up to and including version 3.5 `IsValid` returned `true`... Is it possible that `ConvertFrom` "swallows" the exception?

Comment: According to the docs it should swallow exceptions starting with .NET 4.0. But I tested in a .NET 4.5 project. So I don't get it.

Comment: It is not a bug.  From the MSDN description of TypeConverter.IsValid: "The IsValid method is used to validate a value within the type **rather than to determine if value can be converted to the given type**. For example, IsValid can be used to determine if a given value is valid for an enumeration type."

Comment: @HansPassant That seems to be the case. It was my initial understanding of the usage of `IsValid` method, but I guess I've got sidetracked by the fact that it returns true for `"True"` and `"False"`. Nevertheless, I'll wait for response from the developers. As a side note, I can't help thinking that they just forgot to throw in the check for empty string in `IsValid` - otherwise, can you think of any justification for such design, especially given the remark from @C.Evenhuis?

Answer (score 1):

What different people expect in some of these situations probably isn't the same, but to me the behavior given by the framework in this case seems reasonable.

For example: in the following cases, the behavior seems perfectly reasonable to me.

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(bool?));

bool? nullableBool1 = converter.ConvertFrom(string.Empty); // returns null
bool? nullableBool2 = converter.ConvertFrom("true"); // returns true
bool? nullableBool3 = converter.ConvertFrom("false"); // returns false

bool? nullableBool4 = converter.ConvertFromString(string.Empty); // returns null
bool? nullableBool5 = converter.ConvertFromString("true"); // returns true
bool? nullableBool6 = converter.ConvertFromString("false"); // returns false
```

From @C.Evenhuis' comment, this is the behavior that I believe was deemed questionable.

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(bool?));
var string1 = converter.ConvertToString(null); // returns ""
var string2 = converter.ConvertToString(true); // returns "true"
var string3 = converter.ConvertToString(false); // returns "false"
```

`ConvertToString` is doing something which I find very good.  If you'll note, `var isNullAString = null is string` returns `false`!  It makes more sense to me for null to be converted into an empty string, even if that's not what you were expecting.

As to the last unaddressed part in your question..

> Perhaps I'm wrong, but I'd expect the IsValid method to return false whenever a value cannot be converted and true otherwise, but clearly that's not the case with an empty string and NullableConverter (same behavior can be observed for other nullable types).

I believe this was satisfactorily answered in a comment above, which stated

> The IsValid method is used to validate a value within the type rather than to determine if value can be converted to the given type. For example, IsValid can be used to determine if a given value is valid for an enumeration type.

Answer (score 0):

The Reason you are having the issue is because String.Empty is a class vs "" is a Literal. It is a ReadOnly Varialble. which that means it is a NULL Variable of type string.